# Error - implementing a protocol in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm running the following code:

```
ExHubic.Request.request({:get, "/account", nil, :hubic}, ExHubic)
```

and getting the following error:

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol ExHubic.Request not implemented for {:get, "/account", nil, :hubic}
    (ex_hubic) lib/request.ex:1: ExHubic.Request.impl_for!/1
    (ex_hubic) lib/request.ex:6: ExHubic.Request.request/2
```

This error message suggests to me that the protocol is not implemented for the type  `ExHubic.Query.Hubic.t` which is defined as `@type t :: {atom, String.t, any, :hubic}`

It could well be a problem with the types that I have created but I can't see it.

Some context:

```
defprotocol ExHubic.Request do
  @moduledoc false
  @spec request(query :: ExHubic.Query.t, client :: atom)
                :: ExHubic.Query.http_query_t
  def request(query, client)
end

defimpl ExHubic.Request, for:  ExHubic.Query.Hubic  do
  @spec request(query :: ExHubic.Query.Hubic.t, client :: atom)
                :: {:ok, ExHubic.Client.response_t} | {:error, ExHubic.Client.response_t}
  def request({method, uri, params, :hubic} = query, client) do
     implementation_details
  end
end

defmodule ExHubic.Query do
  @moduledoc false
  @type t ::  {atom, String.t, any, atom}
end

defmodule ExHubic.Query.Hubic do
  @type t :: {atom, String.t, any, :hubic}
  @spec account() :: __MODULE__.t
  def account(), do: {:get, "/account", :nil, :hubic}
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, first of all, you are using an atom (module name) for the protocol. You need to use either a built in type or a struct as described in http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html#protocols-and-structs. This means adding a defstruct to the module:

```
defmodule ExHubic.Query.Hubic do
  defstruct [:method, :uri, :params,  service: :hubic]
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{method: atom, uri: String.t, params: any, service: :hubic}
  def account(), do: {:get, "/account", :nil, :hubic}
end

defprotocol ExHubic.Request do
  def request(query, client)
end


defimpl ExHubic.Request, for:  ExHubic.Query.Hubic  do

  @spec request(Query.t, atom) :: any
  def request(query, client) do
    IO.inspect query
  end
end
```

You can then use this with:

```
ExHubic.Request.request(%ExHubic.Query.Hubic{method: :get, params: nil, service: :hubic, uri: "/account"}, client)
```

Comment: I ran into issues with my previous attempt. Your answer may well be the correct answer but I haven't been able to implement this yet successfully. I'm not going to be at a computer desk for a few weeks. The bit about the tuples not allowed is definitely right and has put me on the right path. But I'm not sure yet if the query or the client should be the first argument. I need to investigate more when I'm back at a desk. Thanks.

Comment: Change tuples to structs fixed it. For reference purposes: Files: [Query](https://github.com/stephenmoloney/ex_hubic/blob/master/lib/query/hubic.ex), [Protocol](https://github.com/stephenmoloney/ex_hubic/blob/master/lib/request.ex), [Protocol Impl](https://github.com/stephenmoloney/ex_hubic/blob/master/lib/request/hubic/request.ex)